# Read STEP file (text) and convert to xml

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, text, step

I am currently working on a converter that is supposed to convert STEP files into my own XML in C#.
I am struggling with the approach of extracting the data out of the STEP file.
For easier use I changed the format from .step/.stp to .txt.

Roughly a STEP file is build of SHAPES, which are created from ADVANCED_SURFACES, which are again created from PLANES and so on. They all contain references to other lines.

```
...
#33=CLOSED_SHELL('',(#34,#35,#36,#37,#38,#39));
#34=ADVANCED_FACE('',(#46),#40,.F.);
...
#40=PLANE('',#127);
...
```

Would it be better to read all shapes first, then use it's values to find the surfaces (re-read it), then planes, etc. or is it simpler / faster to read all lines once, store them in a dictionary and then use the dictionary to find all values?
Am I on the wrong track? Are the other/better approaches?

Comment: How large are the files? Do you have a class structure already?

Comment: Step files go from 200 up to over 150.000 lines (about 3MB).

Comment: What type of XML are you looking to generate?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not sure yet (I'm still in the process). My current problem is to get all the information out of the text file.

Comment: Your going to simply read the data and implement a recursive method to build your object then serialize it to xml.  But, you must first know how you would like to build your object/xml structure.

Comment: A recursive solution hasn't come to my mind, yet.
But wouldn't that imply re-reading the file over and over again until it is solved?
Do you have an example of how it could look like?

Comment: Well, no, because I don't know what you want the result to look like.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I wasn't clear enough. I just meant the reading part. What would be like the easiest way?

Comment: Just the standard old way http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John Saunders  That consensus is about not stuffing titles with all the tags, however it doesn't say that you aren't allowed to use key words in the title that are also tags.  By removing steps you have removed the main gist of the problem, which is how to process the STEP format rather than any old text file.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I only removed C#, not STEP

Comment: No problem.
But do you guys have any more suggestions?